# "that" in there is no question that

Tags: extraposition

I was wondering what the role of **"that"** is in the widely used phrase, "There is no question **that**~".

e.g. There is no question **that** she has a great voice.

I guess **"that"** functions as a conjunction since it is immediately followed by a clause, but what exact role does **"that"** play in terms of the sentence structure?

Is **"that"** functioning as a conjunction leading the appositive clause such as in "The actress hid *the fact* **that** she was married.", to elaborate on the preceding noun "the fact"?.

Or is **"that"** leading the extraposed clause acting as a subject with a dummy subject "there" in the subject position?

Thanks for your insightful feedback in advance.

Comment: Not exactly a conjunction. The technical term is a "complementizer"; it introduces complement clauses, which come in various shapes. One of the types is the _that_-clause, which is just a regular sentence that begins with _that_ and can be used as the subject or object of a verb, like _I think (that) she will be there_ or _That he left early was unfortunate_. So your last guess was the correct one. It's introducing (not leading) the moved subject clause. One of the things that often happens to subject complement clauses is that they get extraposed or  _there_-inserted.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've seen numerous examples of extraposed that-clauses with the dummy subject "it", but I haven't seen that many of them with "there" being in the subject position and that-clause extraposed. Are there any other examples that I can refer to?

Comment: Its category (part of speech) here is **subordinator**, and its function is **marker**. I'd avoid calling it a complementizer because it also occurs in relative clauses, which are modifiers, not complements. In your example "The actress hid the fact [that she was married]", the bracketed bit is not an appositive but a declarative content clause -- it gives the content (meaning) of "question". And in "There is no question [that she has a great voice]", again, "that" introduces a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "question".

Comment: Re you comment, I agree that extraposed clauses involve replacing the subject with "it", and the displaced subject then becomes a non-subject element outside the VP. Your example "There is no question that she has a great voice" is an existential clause with dummy pronoun "there" as subject". It doesn't have a non-existential equivalent: we can't say *"That she has a great voice there is no question"

Comment: Drawing from Prof. Lawler's comment above, it would be better to look for instances of the form which begin with *That*. Especially in older writings.

Comment: @Kris Why? We've already discussed the category and function of "that". In any case, I think he's wrong.

Comment: @BillJ Just because the transposed form is less frequent in usage than the regular.

Comment: @Kris There's no 'extraposed' construction in the OP's question. Clauses with "there" are existential, not extraposed. In any case, very often the _it_ extraposed construction is preferred to the non-extraposed one, in fact it's regarded as the default.

Comment: @BillJ I am not sure you get the drift.

Comment: Yes, the _that_-clause in the OP's question is not extraposed; that would involve a dummy _it_ subject. Instead, the clause is the complement of _question_, which is a picture noun and can take finite complements, particularly in the fixed phrase _no question that `S`_. There has been _there_-insertion in the sentence, but only in the main clause and applying to _the question_, not its complement clause; and in any case that's part of the construction with _no question_. If I gave the wrong impression in my comment above, my apologies.